# Catalyst forgets monitor settings after reboot or log out in 12.10

Tags: hdmi, catalyst, scaling

I have a Samsung monitor connected to my ATI Radeon graphic card via HDMI. By default the screen has a black border around, but I can disable it in the Catalyst menu to get full screen. (There is a scalebar that I have to set to the highest value.) My problem is that every time I turn off and on my computer it changes back and I have to set it up again. It is really annoying. Is there any way to make this setting permanent?

Notes: 1. I open Catalyst with admin rights. 2. When I open the Catalyst settings menu, it looks like that it keeps my settings, because the scalebar stays at the highest point, but still it doesn't scale up my screen until I move back and forth the scale bar to the same point

Update: as a new user I cannot answer this protected question, nut I have found a solution, I also had this same problem. Solution is described at:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

> If you experience underscan when outputting video to an HDTV, this
>   may resolve the issue:
>
> ```
> sudo aticonfig --set-pcs-val=MCIL,DigitalHDTVDefaultUnderscan,0
> sudo reboot
> ```
>
> This sets the default underscan setting to false.

I did it and it finally solved the problem. This may not be the standard way to answer the question, but I think in this case it's more important that Mate knows how to fix it until AMD fixes its CCC finally.

Answer (score 2):

This answer was provided by [Tom Rakoncátlan](https://askubuntu.com/users/113043/tom-rakoncatlan) who as a new user cannot answer this protected question, so I have posted it here on his behalf.

Solution is described at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

Quote: "If you experience underscan when outputting video to an HDTV, this may resolve the issue:

```
sudo aticonfig --set-pcs-val=MCIL,DigitalHDTVDefaultUnderscan,0 sudo reboot
```

This sets the default underscan setting to false." I did it and it finally solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

Cayalyst Control Center -> Display Manager (Adjustments tab) -> Image Options 
    Choose "Use graphics processor for scaling".

In "Graphics processor scaling"
    Choose "Scale image to full panel size".

In "Scaling Options"
    Adjust the scrollbar.

Click "Apply".

Reboot.

Comment: This is what I tried many times before. The problem is that it doesn't keep the settings after reboot

Comment: Is there a 'save' options or button?

Comment: There is an apply button. No joy!! Annoyingly, everything was fine before, but I needed to do a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

try turning your vertical refresh back to default. It just worked for me.